First SEM model and issues with unique factor covariances among reverse scored items in lavaan
Hi everyone: This is my first time doing SEM and I feel super insecure about my code/results. I do not know colleagues that know SEM and also use R, so I will give a try here. The codes run and the results are in line with previous literature:
I wanted to test a 'simple' model with 1 predictor (continuos variable) and 1 outcome (latent bi-factorial continuos variable with 4 factors). The structure of the outcome was identified from previous literature.
First, I conducted a CFA to check the measurement model. I used the author's code and I reversed the negatively worded items before conducting CFA or SEM (the author did not mention any of this). I also include a chunk to estimate unique factor covariances among reverse scores (albeit the reverse scores are now following the same direction than the positively worded items). The code from the original paper is:
model<- 'A =~ stress1 + stress10rev + stress15rev

B =~ stress2N_reversed + stress6N_reversed + stress11rev + stress14rev

C =~ stress4rev + stress7rev + stress8rev + stress9rev + stress17rev

D =~ stress3N_reversed + stress5N_reversed + stress12rev + stress13N_reversed + stress16rev

GENERAL =~ stress3N_reversed + stress5N_reversed + stress12rev + stress13N_reversed +

stress16rev + stress1 + stress10rev + stress15rev + stress4rev + stress7rev +

stress8rev + stress9rev + stress17rev + stress2N_reversed + stress6N_reversed +

stress11rev + stress14rev

estimate unique factor covariances among reverse scored items (not the original, they are reversed)
stress2N_reversed ~~ stress3N_reversed + stress5N_reversed + stress6N_reversed + stress13N_reversed

stress3N_reversed ~~ stress5N_reversed + stress6N_reversed + stress13N_reversed

stress5N_reversed ~~ stress6N_reversed + stress13N_reversed

stress6N_reversed ~~ stress13N_reversed

set orthogonal latent factors
GENERAL ~~

0*A

0*B

0*C

0*D

A ~~

0*B

0*C

0*D

B~~

0*C

0*D

C~~

0*D'

Then, I conducted SEM, using the same code than for model, and adding the regressions:
#regressions
A + B + C +D ~ predictor

GENERAL ~ predictor

Does it make sense? Particularly:

does it make sense to estimate unique factor coviances among reverse scored items (that now follow the direction of the positively worded items)?,
does it makes sense to regress each factor and the general factor? My hypothesis is focused on the general factor, but I want to include the factors in case a reviewer asks for them.

Any insights will be super appreciated!
I have tried to check whether the logic of the code is correct, but have not found similar examples
